# Rails 5.2: No such middleware to insert before: "Warden::Manager"

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-5, apartment-gem

I get this error trying to run a local rails server for an app upgraded to Rails 5.2 beta2:

> gems/actionpack-5.2.0.beta2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:108:in `assert_index': No such middleware to insert before: "Warden::Manager" (RuntimeError)

I am using Devise.

**Update:**
Error is related to apartment gem with Devise on Rails 5.2.
This line in initializers/apartment.rb

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 'Warden::Manager', 'Apartment::Elevators::Subdomain'
```

Seems to be related. It works fine with Rails 4.10

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed by changing the class name strings to reference the actual classes in the apartment initializer:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use Apartment::Elevators::Subdomain
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before Warden::Manager, Apartment::Elevators::Subdomain
```

Comment: if there is another error `uninitialized constant Apartment::Elevators (NameError)` just add `require 'apartment/elevators/subdomain'` to the top of your `application.rb`.